# Sending contact over bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hello i was wondering how to send a contact over bluetooth to another device. I used this code but its from an image. I just want to know how to send the contact.

https://github.com/unixpickle/ImageTransfer

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Project [BTLE Transfer Bluetooth of Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html)

It is a demo Project that transfers Text whatever you write on Peripheral Device to Central Device.

In same manner you can transfer your Contact in place of Text with encoding

I hope this will solves your problem.

Comment: Do you know what i would send the contact as? txt or pdf..... Then how the recipient would open it. Thanks!

Comment: i guessed contact is in String form and convert that string into NSData then send it